# Running Android studio on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, android-studio

I am newbie to Ubuntu. I have Android Studio for Ubuntu and Android-SDK with me. When I run

```
./studio.sh
```

from andriod-studio/bin, it shows an error as "command not found".Then how should I run (open the IDE) from Ubuntu? I am using Ubuntu 14.4LTS.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Superuser! Could you add some more information about where your install is located, and perhaps an `ls` of the directory? As it stands, your question is really hard to answer and is likely to be downvoted and/or closed.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the file studio.sh is either not in your current directory.
, its not set to be executable so cannot be found as a command or one of the commands with in it cannot be found.

You can check by running 'ls -l studio.sh' , then if that says 
 No such file or directory then you are in the wrong directory,
use 'cd directory' to change to a directory called directory.

if you get something like this then it exists but isn't executable
-rw-r--r--  1 user group   9172 Mar 26  2014 studio.sh

to make it executable run 'chown u+x studio.sh' and then try the ls
command again (press up to go back through history) and if its worked you should see -rwx-r--r-- .

It should then be runnable as ./studio.sh if you are in the same directory as it.

One possible issue is that one of the commands inside the studio.sh (which is a list of shell commands) cannot be found , if this is the case your studio.sh probably already has the x set and your installation is not correct.

you can diagnose this by running studio.sh in debug mode which can be done by doing 'bash -x ./studio.sh' , this will give much more info about what is happening and should show you what is missing. You could also try bash -e to make it stop exactly at the erroring command.